# Example of a compact subset that is not closed

Tags: general-topology, compactness, separation-axioms

What would be an example of a compact subset A of a $T_1$ such that A is not closed?

**My attempt:** $T_1$ is a space such that if we take any two points $x,y\in X$ then $\exists $ open set containing x but not y and vice-versa.

One example of $T_1$ space is an $\mathbb{R}$ with cofinite topology. Closed sets in the finite complement topology are the finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ as well as $\mathbb{R}$.
So if we take any open interval then it is compact however it is not closed since the complement is not finite. Is it true?

Comment: The empty set is always open and closed

Comment: Sorry i wanted to write in a different way, can you have a look now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty set is not a problem: it's finite and it's closed and it's compact.

But note that **any** subset of $\mathbb{R}$ in the cofinite topology is compact. The same argument that shows the whole space is compact also works for any subset.

But the **only** closed subsets are the finite ones, so take $A = \mathbb{N}$ as an example of a compact non-closed subspace. Your open interval is fine too.